# Получить название колонки БД для показа оставшихся размеров товара

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, linq

Существует модель размеров ProductSize, где есть свойства:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public int S {get; set;}
public int M {get; set;}
public int L {get; set;}
public int ProductId {get;set;}
public Product Product {get; set;}
```

Размеры хранят в себе значение Int, которые указывают на количество в наличии того или иного размера. Хочу создать дропдаун, в котором будут только указаны размеры, в которых значение больше нуля. Ну или, как вариант, будут все значения, но Enabled\Disabled по этой же логике. Но для этого мне все равно нужно получить названия колонок, в которых ненулевые значения.
Как правильно будет это сделать?

Сначала вместо int хранил bool и написал этот ужасный метод (но по итогу даже не попробовал, потому что решил переделать всю БД сначала)

```
var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == productId);
var availableSizes = from s in db.ProductSizes where (s.Id == productId) select s;
List<string> Sizes = new List<string>();
foreach (var s in availableSizes)
{
    if(s.S == true)
    {
        Sizes.Add("S");
    }
    if(s.M == true)
    {
        Sizes.Add("M");
    }
    if (s.L == true)
    {
        Sizes.Add("L");
    }
    if (s.Xl == true)
    {
        Sizes.Add("XL");
    }
    if (s.Xxl == true)
    {
        Sizes.Add("XXL");
    }
}
return Sizes;
```

Comment: Думаю, вам лучше пересмотреть модель. Заведите сущность "Размер" отдельно. Тогда, вам не понадобится этот "ужасный метод", вам не придется менять модель (да и вообще писать код) когда вы начнете продавать вещи XXXXXL или какого-то нестандартного размера

Comment: @АндрейNOP я не очень понимаю, что подразумевается под сущностью - отдельная таблица, столбец или что? Просто для меня довольно размытое понятие, я только недавно начал изучать БД и эту технологию

Comment: Сущность = класс модели ≈ таблица БД

Comment: @АндрейNOP и в моем случае эта сущность должна будет хранить строковое значение размера(его название) или как?

Comment: Да, строковое значение названия и любые другие характеристики, например обозначение российского размера, международного, размеры в сантиметрах, да все что угодно, ограничений нет

Comment: @АндрейNOP не вижу никаких стрелок или чего-либо около вашего комментария, чтобы отметить его полезным\ответом, только флажок, можно ли как-то еще это сделать?

Comment: Только когда @АндрейNOP появится и напишет полноценный ответ. Подождите, возможно сегодня-завтра. Тут я тоже за передлку модели. Размеры - это только про виды размеров, а наличие/отстутствие - это как минимум отдельная модель (а то и вообще по-хорошему модель складских остатков "поступило на склад", "продано" и т.п.)

Comment: В ближайшие несколько дней точно не смогу написать нормальный ответ. В принципе, я не против, чтобы его написал кто-то другой. @AK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта. Полноценный - это создавать хорошую структуру для товаров, складских остатков, проданного и списанного товара.

Но в принципе, если вы не планируете двигаться в эту сторону - то посмотрите в сторону более простой модели.

У вас отдельно должны быть размеры:

```
public class ProductSize
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Title { get; set; }
}
```

И отдельно их наличие:

```
public class Store
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   public Product Product {get; set;}
   public int ProductSizeId {get;set;}
   public ProductSize ProductSize {get; set;}
   public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

В котором заполняйте количество товаров того или иного размера отдельными строками. Запросы будут гораздо проще, тут их два варианта: либо вы один продуктов+размер может иметь только одну строку в таблице, либо несколько, нужно предварительно просуммировать.

Уверен: вы очень быстро найдёте для себя много идей как пойти к полноценной складской системе :)